# Basic PHP Object Oriented MYSQL Query

Tags: php

So I've been learning for about 3 months now and am currently using very old procedural techniques and the deprecated mysql extension in my code.  So time to take a step forward, ditch my procedural ways and get into object oriented / prepared statements...

This is very basic but I guess everyone has to learn some day.  I'm trying to get retrieve and simple dataset from mysql database..

so far I have my connection:

```
$useri = new mysqli('localhost', 'useri', 'xxx','yyy');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
        }
```

I get no errors so I assume this works, and I have my query:

```
$test_query = "SELECT * FROM t";
$test_query = $useri->real_escape_string($test_query);
 echo $test_query;
  if($result = $useri->query($test_query)){
   while($row = $useri->fetch_object($result)){
    echo $row->id;
 }
 $result->close();
}
$useri->close();
```

However I get no results... so, 2 questions:

a. what am I doing wrong? and

b. anyone recommend any good tutorials apart from the php manual for this stuff?

Thanks   :)

Comment: Check w3schools. Its good and given brief idea.

Comment: You need a space between the * and the word FROM in your select query

Comment: that was just a formatting error when transferring my code..

Comment: try this:   while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { insted of this:  while($row = $useri->fetch_object($result)){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for one of the table i have in my db:

```
$useri = new mysqli('localhost', 'useri', 'xxx','yyy');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$test_query = "SELECT * FROM t";
$test_query = $useri->real_escape_string($test_query);
  if($result = $useri->query($test_query)){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { //only this is changed
    echo $row->id;
  }
 $result->close();
 }else{ //check for error if query was wrong
 echo $useri->error;
 }
 $useri->close();
```

Comment: this code works if you query right table on right database,and if your  table contain id row. Try printing error if $results is not fetched with $useri->error;

Comment: the error shows that it is the escaping interfering with the query.  If I remove the real_escape_string it works fine, and I suppose it doesn't actually need escaping if I'm going to use a prepare statement...  Thank you for your time, much appreciated   :)

Comment: Why is it so repetitive? I don't see any simplicity in it.

Comment: because simplicity was not my goal, i explained what line is changed. just want to put whole code for context.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure that you have a space after `*`

   ```
   $test_query = "SELECT * FROM t";
   ```
2. check this tutorial

   http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/
   http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: 1 - typo transferring the code.  2.  Thanks for those, will give them a read through   :)